# Serial port in C++ on Linux. Can read and write on serial port happen simultaneously..?

Tags: c++, linux, serialization

I am working on a project which needs a Linux PC to take data from a micro controller on UART, for which I have used an already available open source code for serial port in C++ for linux. (Ros (robotic operating system) based code)

The code goes as below:

```
#define DEFAULT_BAUDRATE 115200
#define DEFAULT_SERIALPORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

//Global data
FILE *fpSerial = NULL;   //serial port file pointer
ros::Publisher ucResponseMsg;
ros::Subscriber ucCommandMsg;
int ucIndex;          //ucontroller index number

int FileDesc;

unsigned char crc_sum=0;

//Initialize serial port, return file descriptor
FILE *serialInit(char * port, int baud)
{
  int BAUD = 0;
  int fd = -1;
  struct termios newtio, oldtio;
  FILE *fp = NULL;

 //Open the serial port as a file descriptor for low level configuration
 // read/write, not controlling terminal for process,
  fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

  ROS_INFO("FileDesc : %d",fd);

 if ( fd<0 )
  {
    ROS_ERROR("serialInit: Could not open serial device %s",port);
   return fp;
  }

  // save current serial port settings
  tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio);

  // clear the struct for new port settings
  bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));

  //Look up appropriate baud rate constant
  switch (baud)
  {
     case 38400:
     default:
        BAUD = B38400;
        break;
     case 19200:
        BAUD  = B19200;
        break;
    case 115200:
        BAUD  = B115200;
        break;
     case 9600:
       BAUD  = B9600;
        break;
     case 4800:
        BAUD  = B4800;
        break;
     case 2400:
        BAUD  = B2400;
        break;
     case 1800:
        BAUD  = B1800;
        break;
     case 1200:
        BAUD  = B1200;
        break;
  }  //end of switch baud_rate

  if (cfsetispeed(&newtio, BAUD) < 0 || cfsetospeed(&newtio, BAUD) < 0)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("serialInit: Failed to set serial baud rate: %d", baud);
    close(fd);
    return NULL;
  }

  // set baud rate, (8bit,noparity, 1 stopbit), local control, enable receiving characters.
  newtio.c_cflag  = BAUD | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;

  // ignore bytes with parity errors
  newtio.c_iflag =  IGNPAR;

  // raw output
  newtio.c_oflag = 0;

  // set input mode to non - canonical
  newtio.c_lflag = 0;

  // inter-charcter timer 
  newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

  // blocking read (blocks the read until the no.of charcters are read
  newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

  // clean the line and activate the settings for the port
  tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
  tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW,&newtio);

  //Open file as a standard I/O stream
  fp = fdopen(fd, "r+");

 if (!fp) {
    ROS_ERROR("serialInit: Failed to open serial stream %s", port);
    fp = NULL;
  }

ROS_INFO("FileStandard I/O stream: %d",fp);

  return fp;
} //serialInit


//Process ROS command message, send to uController
void ucCommandCallback(const geometry_msgs::TwistConstPtr& cmd_vel)
{
  unsigned char msg[14];
  float test1,test2;
  unsigned long i;

 // build the message packet to be sent
 msg = packet to be sent;
 msg[13] = crc_sum;

   for (i=0;i<14;i++)
   {
     fprintf(fpSerial, "%c", msg[i]);
   }

tcflush(FileDesc, TCOFLUSH); 

} //ucCommandCallback


//Receive command responses from robot uController
//and publish as a ROS message
void *rcvThread(void *arg)
{
  int rcvBufSize = 200;
  char ucResponse[10];//[rcvBufSize];   //response string from uController
  char *bufPos;
  std_msgs::String msg;
  std::stringstream ss;
  int BufPos,i;
  unsigned char crc_rx_sum =0;

  while (ros::ok()) {

     BufPos = fread((void*)ucResponse,1,10,fpSerial);

for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 ROS_INFO("T: %x ",(unsigned char)ucResponse[i]);
 ROS_INFO("NT: %x ",ucResponse[i]);
}

          msg.data = ucResponse;
          ucResponseMsg.publish(msg);
}

  return NULL;
} //rcvThread


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char port[20];    //port name
  int baud;     //baud rate 

  char topicSubscribe[20];
  char topicPublish[20];

  pthread_t rcvThrID;   //receive thread ID
  int err;

  //Initialize ROS
  ros::init(argc, argv, "r2SerialDriver");
  ros::NodeHandle rosNode;
  ROS_INFO("r2Serial starting");

  //Open and initialize the serial port to the uController
  if (argc > 1) {
    if(sscanf(argv[1],"%d", &ucIndex)==1) {
      sprintf(topicSubscribe, "uc%dCommand",ucIndex);
      sprintf(topicPublish, "uc%dResponse",ucIndex);
    }
    else {
      ROS_ERROR("ucontroller index parameter invalid");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    strcpy(topicSubscribe, "uc0Command");
    strcpy(topicPublish, "uc0Response");
  }

  strcpy(port, DEFAULT_SERIALPORT);
  if (argc > 2)
     strcpy(port, argv[2]);

  baud = DEFAULT_BAUDRATE;
  if (argc > 3) {
    if(sscanf(argv[3],"%d", &baud)!=1) {
      ROS_ERROR("ucontroller baud rate parameter invalid");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  ROS_INFO("connection initializing (%s) at %d baud", port, baud);

   fpSerial = serialInit(port, baud);

 if (!fpSerial )
  {
    ROS_ERROR("unable to create a new serial port");
    return 1;
  }
  ROS_INFO("serial connection successful");

  //Subscribe to ROS messages
  ucCommandMsg = rosNode.subscribe("cmd_vel" /*topicSubscribe*/, 100, ucCommandCallback);

  //Setup to publish ROS messages
  ucResponseMsg = rosNode.advertise<std_msgs::String>(topicPublish, 100);

  //Create receive thread
  err = pthread_create(&rcvThrID, NULL, rcvThread, NULL);

  if (err != 0) {
    ROS_ERROR("unable to create receive thread");
    return 1;
  }

  //Process ROS messages and send serial commands to uController
  ros::spin();

  fclose(fpSerial);
  ROS_INFO("r2Serial stopping");
  return 0;
}
```

You can leave the ROS part aside, but the problem is with the serial port code.

When I run this code, I receive the data from the controller correctly, but even when controller stops sending the data also I see the same data coming on the `printf`s continuously. Is this the problem of not flushing the input buffers?

But I am unable to send the data from the Linux PC to the controller, no idea what is happening, can read and write happen simultaneously on serial port in linux?

Strange observation, when I open the port in H-term (an uART visualizer similar to that of hyper terminal) with my serial port code running at the back end, still the H-term doesn't give any error, but ideally H-term should give an error saying "the port can not be opened it is locked", but this doesn't happen, is my code not acquiring a lock on the serial port?

And when I connect the port using H-term with mu serial port code running then I can see the data coming on the UART from linux-PC to the micro controller?

Can any one have any insights to the problems I am facing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had similar problems. Make sure the data is flushed and so on. Apart from that I've seen that the stability of the UART communication can be correlated to the baud rate. Also, check out https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty, it's really useful for troublehsooting these kinds of problems.

Comment: Data Flushed means, can You elobarate please.

Comment: When you use `fprintf` the data is not written until you either print a newline, or do fflush.

Comment: And the other issues?

Comment: No I am using the fwrite now (follwing @laune comment).

Comment: But still the question how can the H-term is able to connect to the port when I running the code at back end, in which the port is already open.

Comment: You're not configuring the serial port properly.  Study [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  *"Can read and write on serial port happen simultaneously?"* -- Yes, assuming you actually have full-duplex hardware on both ends.  But since RS-232 is a point-to-point link and typically a master-slave relationship or a request-response dialog, you will rarely see simultaneous I/O.

Comment: If you do not open the serial port exclusively, then another program can also open that serial port.  More than one program reading from the serial port will be unpredictable, as will writing.  "Sharing" a character device in unlike sharing a block device.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
BufPos = fread((void*)ucResponse,1,10,fpSerial);
```

because there is no check whether BufPos is zero or less than 10

Rather than ros::ok, use feof() (after receiving 0 bytes) to check for a closed connection, and ferror() to check for errors. Or stop calling fread when you know (according to the protocol) that a packet of data has been received.

It is possible to use a serival port in full duplex mode (i.e., read and write) not exactly "simultaneously" but alternatively. Partners must follow protocol to avoid misunderstandings.

Don't mix fprintf and fread/fwrite. For sending, fwrite is indicated.

Comment: I have used fwrite instead of fprintf, still the same behaviour.